# symbols for exponentiation

Tags: notation

In thinking about [this question on PLDI](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1959/285) I wondered if there are any other mathematical symbols which represent exponentiation as an infix operator.

x `pow` y  -->  x<sup>y</sup>

Commonly used notations in programming are caret ^ (which often has other meanings relating to logic) and double star **.

Even better if there is a matching unicode symbol (though I haven't found any likely candiates looking through unicode tables).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_programming_languages) gives `↑` (ALGOL, Commodore BASIC), `^^` (Haskell, D), and `⋆` (APL).

Comment: Good point. I will mention those in my answer to the linked question.